# User domain CA to create a UCC cert

Tags: ssl-certificate, remote-desktop, rdp, certificate-authority

We have 30+ RDS servers and use a hardware load balancer.
I'm trying to figure out how to generate a UCC cert from our in house CA.

Anyone point me in the right direction to do so? Need to alias all RDS server names so when users bounce servers they don't keep seeing the trusted cert screen because the server they connect to isn't the same name they are pointed to (load balancer)

Answer (score 4):

A UCC cert is more of a marketing term than a technically different type of certificate. A UCC cert is really just a regular X509 certificate with a bunch of SANs (subject alternative names) on it. As such, you can easily mimic the functionality of such a cert with your own internal certification authority. If you own the CA, you can have it issue certificates with literally any combination of CNs and SANs you can dream of.

[image: UCC and SAN]

"UCC certs" and "SAN certs" are essentially the same thing.

If I were you, I would duplicate a Server Auth. certificate template from your CA, and give manual enroll permissions to your group of RDS servers. I would make sure to modify the template to require additional information so that you have the opportunity to input additional SANs (as DNS names, probably) at the time that you enroll. I would also make the private key exportable, so that you can then share that certificate among all your RDS servers, or upload it to your hardware load balancer, as the case may be.

This is a screen like your client would see (similar to - just an example) when he is trying to enroll in a certificate from your Enterprise CA. You get here by going to mmc -> Add snapin -> certificates, then right click and choose enroll.

[image: AD Enroll]

What the client sees in this screen is determined by what certificate templates your Enterprise CA has been configured to offer (and what he has permissions to.)

If your CA and clients are not joined to the same domain, then you would instead need to go through Certificate Services Web Enrollment. It provides an old-school web interface to request certificates.

Instead of an EKU of Server Authentication, you may need a Remote Desktop Server Authentication EKU. See details here: http://www.derekseaman.com/2013/01/creating-custom-remote-desktop-services.html

Comment: I was able to create the cert but when I edit the RDP settings for RDS services and choose 'Select' for the cert it tells me that there are no certs installed. I have imported the cert under personal and remote desktop of the computer but no luck.

Comment: I'm sorry - try a Remote Desktop Authentication EKU:  http://www.derekseaman.com/2013/01/creating-custom-remote-desktop-services.html